# Advice on SELECT statement and query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to either have a masive select statement or multiple queries.  I need to break down data into specific timeframes during the day.  This one works great for the first interval, but after that I'm stumped.  If I have multiple queries, I'm having trouble with my "mysql_fetch_array", as to the syntax (using something like 'else' and going through them).

```
SELECT U.user_name,ROUND(SUM((TA.task_average*TC.completed)/60),2) AS equiv1, S.submit_date,
    SUM(TC.completed) AS ttasks1,
    FROM `summary` S
    JOIN users U ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN tasks TA ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    JOIN tcompleted TC ON TC.tcompleted_id = S.tcompleted_id
    JOIN minutes M ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    WHERE DATE(submit_date) = curdate( )
      AND TIME(submit_date) BETWEEN '06:00:00' and '07:59:59'       
      GROUP BY U.user_name
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

My fetch array ( I would need to have a bunch more, but how to I combine them?)

```
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

?>
```

Comment: Whenever possible, try and use `X BETWEEN ? AND ?` instead of `X > ? AND X < ?`. This is often faster in terms of execution because the optimizer is happier.

Comment: use of mysql_fetch_array is 'discouraged' http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php try using mysqli instead and this might also help with a solution

Comment: @caitriona: exactly how would changing db libraries help the OP? "red cars get groceries from the store better than blue cars"?

Comment: the part where he says 'I'm having trouble with my "mysql_fetch_array", as to the syntax'?

Comment: Great suggestions - let me try them and I'll post the results. Thank you!

Comment: After playing around with this some more, I'm still stumped.  I need to display various timeframes of the day into one html table.  Is multiple SELECT statements the best way to do this? --or is it possible to do this with one SELECT statement?

Comment: are the timeframes consistent throughout the day - eg. always a 2 hour period as in your query above, or do they vary in time?

Comment: consistent 2 hour increments; 6-8am, 8-10am, etc..

Comment: I should add, and then I'm trying to output the values into separate columns in the html table.  The first interval works great but can't figure out the best way to include the rest of the time intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, given that you want the data across regular 2 hourly intervals, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT FLOOR(hour(S.submit_date)/2)*2, U.user_name,ROUND(SUM((TA.task_average*TC.completed)/60),2) AS equiv1, S.submit_date
    SUM(TC.completed) AS ttasks1,
    FROM `summary` S
    JOIN users U ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN tasks TA ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    JOIN tcompleted TC ON TC.tcompleted_id = S.tcompleted_id
    JOIN minutes M ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    WHERE DATE(submit_date) = curdate( )
      GROUP BY U.user_name, FLOOR(hour(S.submit_date)/2)
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

where `FLOOR(hour(S.submit_date)/2)*2` will map each hour to the first (even) hour of every 2 and you can group by this value. ie.

```
0, 1 -> 0
2, 3 -> 2
4, 5 -> 4
etc...
```

---

### update with php included:

some notes:

- i've used mysqli
- i've left joined the original query with an `hours` derived table to ensure there are no
  'gaps' in the time intervals (assumed 6:00 - 20:00)
- i've ordered by `user`, so we as we loop through the results we can print table cells for a given user and then print a new table row when the user changes.

here's the code:

```
echo '<table border=1><tr><td></td>';
for ($i=6; $i<=18; $i=$i+2) {
    echo '<td colspan=2>'.$i.' - '.($i+2).'</td>';
}

$mysqli = new mysqli('MY_HOST', 'MY_USER', 'MY_PASSWORD', 'MY_DATABASE');

$sql = "
SELECT user_name, IFNULL(equiv1,0) AS equiv1, IFNULL(ttasks1,0) AS ttasks1, hour
FROM
(
    SELECT 6 AS hour
    UNION SELECT 8
    UNION SELECT 10
    UNION SELECT 12
    UNION SELECT 14
    UNION SELECT 16
    UNION SELECT 18
) hours LEFT JOIN

(
SELECT FLOOR(hour(S.submit_date)/2)*2 as task_hour, U.user_name, ROUND(SUM((TA.task_average*TC.completed)/60),2) AS equiv1, S.submit_date
    SUM(TC.completed) AS ttasks1
    FROM `summary` S
    JOIN users U ON U.user_id = S.user_id
    JOIN tasks TA ON TA.task_id = S.task_id
    JOIN tcompleted TC ON TC.tcompleted_id = S.tcompleted_id
    JOIN minutes M ON M.minutes_id = S.minutes_id
    WHERE DATE(submit_date) = curdate( )
      GROUP BY U.user_name, FLOOR(hour(S.submit_date)/2)
    LIMIT 0 , 30
) task_summary
ON hours.hour = task_summary.task_hour
ORDER BY user_name, hour
";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$user_name = '';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($user_name <> $row['user_name']){
        echo '</tr><tr><td>'.$row['user_name'].'</td>'; //start a new row if user changes
        $user_name = $row['user_name']; //update user variable for checking on next iteration
    }
    echo '<td>'.$row['equiv1'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['ttasks1'].'</td>';
}

echo '</tr><table>';
```

Comment: Ahh ok, I see what you did. I apologize, I should have specified. I want to capture and post the 2hr intervals as the day goes on. So basically, when I go to the page I want to see all data for all interval periods.   <tr>6-8am heading, 8-10am heading, etc...  underneath <td> with each $row of interval data.

Comment: you'll have to 'infer' the upper hour limit (just add 2) and the am/pm (easiest to do in php) but this should still produce that data. there'll be gaps where there is no data (either because there was none, or the time has not yet occurred) but if that's the problem, it's easy enough to fix.

Comment: So close! :) Ok, I apologize but I am learning and I'm not sure what you are referring to with the infer and adding 2 along with the am/pm. I'd rather just keep it in 24h time if possible. Also, How do I get the values to increment per timeframe --- I'm struggling on that piece. Meaning, the aliases are called "equiv1" and "ttasks1" so with each incrementing timeframe how do i get the values to change/update in my html table? Thank you!

Comment: ok, i wasn't understanding your question correctly. i think i see what you want now. i'll edit the answer.

Comment: Wow!  Ok, that was a lot more than I had expected for coding..eek.  I GREATLY appreciate it!  It works, except that it doesn't shift the data over into the next column during the next interval. It stacks them all in the first column.

Comment: @mike I've made a few assumptions about your table format - it's possible they were incorrect, but the bones of it is there. Have a play around and see if you can get it to work with some tweaking.

Comment: Will do!  I appreciate all of your help! :)

Comment: Your additions worked much better than I realized!  Its more "live" than I had anticipated. So, if I add a record in the DB for a future DATETIME... it won't add it to that interval until the actual server time! I like it! :)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is in regard to your question "how to combine the fetch array". 
Why not have an array to store all the values coming from your fetch array like the one below.

```
<?php
$customArray = array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

    $customArray['field1'] = $row['field1'];
    $customArray['field2'] = $row['field2'];

}

//another fetch array

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

    $customArray['field1'] = $row['field1'];
    $customArray['field2'] = $row['field2'];

}

//now $customArray will have all the required values you need. 
//This is not a great option as it is making the logic expensive. 
//Are you going to use this in a cron job ?
?>
```